# JVMterminated Exit code = -1

Tags: java, jvm, myeclipse

After changing parameter settings in myEclipse and clicking restart, I am getting an error message with header JVMterminated Exit code = -1.

I restart my computer and tried a lot but did not solve my problem. Please guide me what is wrong with myEclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your change in Eclipse's configuration is actually causing errors on it's initialization, hence the -1 exit code.

When the JVM exits with a code different from 0, the convention dictates that is is because of some error.

Try rolling back your changes and see what happens.